# How to drop columns in a table, where column names are "index" and " Unnamed: 0" in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I imported a dataframe via python to mysql server as a table (table-name = tips). During the process, I accidentally add columns named "index" and "Unnamed: 0" to mysql server. I tried different ways to delete the columns like below.

```
alter table tips drop 'index';
alter table tips drop column 'index';
alter table tips drop [index];
alter table tips drop ['index'];
```

For all the statements above for column "index" below is the error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''index'' at line 1
```

I tried the same for 'Unnamed: 0'

```
alter table tips drop 'Unnamed: 0';
alter table tips drop column 'Unnamed: 0';
alter table tips drop [Unnamed: 0];
alter table tips drop ['Unnamed: 0'];
```

For all the statements above for "Unnamed: 0" below is the error.

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Unnamed: 0'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names need to be quoted inside backticks (`) when they contain reserved words or invalid characters. Use this instead:

```
alter table tips drop column `index`, drop column `Unnamed: 0`
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=694e30bce42f43d6438c6be7e29f0dcb)